# window.print() doesn't work on mobile browswer

Tags: javascript

I'm using this function to open a new tab with the html content take from another file and then print it. When I use it on a descktop browser it works fine. It opens a new tab with the content give and prints the page but when I try to do it from my mobile device the tab opens with its content and then I get the printer popup window but it says "There was a problem printing the page. Please try again." I've tried to press retry but it doesn't do anything.

Here's the function.

```
    function printit() {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "/Doc/New Text Document.html", false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                var myWindow = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
                myWindow.document.write(allText);

                myWindow.document.close();
                myWindow.focus();
                myWindow.print();
                myWindow.close();
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Comment: If the problem is specific to a certain device/browser, it's important yo include those details in the question. Which mobile browser are you using? On which platform?

Comment: @DBS I have tried using different mobile devices and mobile browsers and i get the same result

Comment: @Bravo i tried using window.print() on the page from where i call this function and it does print and i also can print from all the pages ive tried.

Comment: @Bravo I have tried removing it and it still doesn't work. I also tried removing `myWindow.document.close();myWindow.focus();` 1 at a time and I still can't get it to work.

Comment: @Bravo I just figured out that it works when i am using incognito. Any idea why that's the case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407175/showing-there-was-a-problem-with-printing-the-page-in-mobile-browsers-window-pr I posted my own question, could you please answer me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407175/showing-there-was-a-problem-with-printing-the-page-in-mobile-browsers-window-pr I have posted my question, could please help me

Comment: @Shatsuki I have added my own question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407175/showing-there-was-a-problem-with-printing-the-page-in-mobile-browsers-window-pr