# Showing There was a problem with printing the page in mobile browsers, window.print using reactjs is not supporting in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Print preview is opening in desktop chrome browser but but it is not opening in mobile browsers.
It is showing there was a problem with printing the page.
If I use this code it is not working in mobile browsers, it is showing the there was a problem with printing page. but it is working in desktop

```
print() {

var print = window.open("", "", "left=0,top=0,width=800,height=500, scrollbars=1"); 

var pcontents= this.state.print; 

// In this.state.print am getting response from api with html tags like header and paragraph tags

print.focus(); 

print.document.write(pcontents);

print.document.close();

print.print();

print.close();

}
```

Comment: Any one could you please answer me about this problem I tried all the possibilities  am not able to find the solution

Comment: Does your printer service open?

Answer (score 2):

Add a timeout function to your `print.close()`, so you allow the printing service on your mobile to get the data before the page closes.

It should look something like this:

```
print.print();
setTimeout(function (){
   print.close();
}, 2000);
```

2000 is the time in milliseconds for the delay. If your printing service is slow then this will not work either.

What you can do is call your `print.close()` manually after the printing is done by calling it after an event. For example a swipe so there is not a button on your window wich would also be printed.

This is a swipe detect function.

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);        
document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

var xDown = null;                                                        
var yDown = null;

function getTouches(evt) {
  return evt.touches ||             // browser API
         evt.originalEvent.touches; // jQuery
}                                                     
                                                                         
function handleTouchStart(evt) {
    const firstTouch = getTouches(evt)[0];                                      
    xDown = firstTouch.clientX;                                      
    yDown = firstTouch.clientY;                                      
};                                                
                                                                         
function handleTouchMove(evt) {
    if ( ! xDown || ! yDown ) {
        return;
    }

    var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
    var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

    var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
    var yDiff = yDown - yUp;
                                                                         
    if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {/*most significant*/
        if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
            /* right swipe */ 
        } else {
            /* left swipe */
        }                       
    } else {
        if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
            /* down swipe */ 
        } else { 
            /* up swipe */
        }                                                                 
    }
    /* reset values */
    xDown = null;
    yDown = null;                                             
};
```